# Regex match that exclude certain pattern

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to split the string around for comma(`,`) or `&`. This is simple but I want to stop the  match for any content between brackets. 
For example if I run on

```
sleeping , waking(sit,stop)
```

there need to be only one split and two elements

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more sample input and expected outputs? For example you mentioned `&`, how should it behave?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example for the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism `PCRE` (and thus `PHP`) offers.
You could come up with the following code:

```
<?php
$string = 'sleeping , waking(sit,stop)';
$regex = '~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[,&]~';
# match anything between ( and ) and discard it afterwards
# instead match any of the characters found on the right in square brackets
$parts = preg_split($regex, $string);
print_r($parts);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => sleeping 
    [1] =>  waking(sit,stop)
)
*/

?>
```

This will split any `,` or `&` which is **not** in parentheses.